# Collections.sort using ArrayList error in java ( Apologise in advance for any English mistakes )

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
public class Receipt implements Comparable<Receipt>
{
  private int number;
  private int customer;
  private float amount;
  public static boolean compare_by_customer = false;

 public Receipt(String line){
 // System.out.println(line);
  String[] split = line.split(",");

  number = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
  //System.out.println(split[1]);


  customer = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
  //System.out.println(split[1] );


  amount = Float.parseFloat(split[2].substring(1));

    // System.out.println(split[2].substring(1));

    }

    public int compareTo(Receipt other){
   return (compare_by_customer)? customer-other.customer : number-           other.number;
   }

   public String toString(){
     return       String.valueOf(number)+","+String.valueOf(customer)+",$"+String.valueOf(amount);
}
}
```

I got the following error eventhough I have overridden compareTo method in my receipt class to use as an arrayList. Can anyone explain the reason for the error please.

```
Main.java:28: error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>>)
                      array.sort(array); work = false; break;
                                   ^
    method List.sort(Comparator<? super Comparable<Receipt>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super Comparable<Receipt>>)
    method ArrayList.sort(Comparator<? super Comparable<Receipt>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super Comparable<Receipt>>)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `sort` method?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: I even tried with using Collections.sort(array) but got same error

Comment: `array.sort(array);` makes no sense at all. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) makes it clear what this method expects and it is ***not*** the same list it has been called on.

Comment: Also there is no `Collection.Sort()`. Either you mean `Collections.sort()` or `List.sort()`. You're trying to use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>> array = reader.getReceipts();
```

to

```
ArrayList<Receipt> array = reader.getReceipts();
```

Use collections.sort() .it will work.

Comment: Share your other algorithm. And what is this code stands for array.sort(array). It makes no sense. If you want to use Collections.sort(list). Then u have to change the generic what i point out.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually calling function sort on List object

```
List.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)
```

Its expecting an instance of Comparator, but you are passing object of ArrayList as parameter.

You can call `array.sort(null);`

Or if you want to use utility class Collections for sorting, then you can call as below

```
 Collections.sort(array);
```

Comment: but why giving error when I am trying to pass array which is type of ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>> ?

Comment: List.sort() required only parameter type of Comparator and ArrayList is not satisfying instanceof test.

Means ArrayList  is not instanceof Comparator. 

That's why you are getting exception 

     **(argument mismatch; ArrayList<Comparable<Receipt>> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super Comparable<Receipt>>)**

Answer (score 0):

Try `ArrayList<Receipt> array = reader.getReceipts();`

The exception comes from the method invocation that you are trying to run.
the sort() method invoked on List takes as parameter the implementation on a comparator that determinates the order of elements in the list (you need to implement the compare(T o1, T o2) method from that interface, or use Collections.sort() to use the Coparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `sort()` for ArrayList or its super classes. Therefore, you should be getting a Compilation Error stating that the method `sort` is undefined.

List type of your collection is also not correct. You would want to use collection of `Receipt`, not a collection of objects of `Comparable` type. So your collection decleration should be as follows.(You should also change the getReceipts method so that it returns an ArrayList of Receipt.)

```
ArrayList<Receipt> array = reader.getReceipts();
```

Lastly, call the Collections.sort() properly.

```
case 4: Collections.sort(array); break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a closer look at how your braces line up as it appears in your post that `sortMenu()` is never called because it is embedded in your main method. I would separate the `sortMenu()` method from the main like below then call it from main. Your `Receipt` class looks fine, but you are not implementing the `compareTo` method properly when you make the array and try to sort it. The lines you need to change are: Separate the `main` method and `sortMenu` method like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  sortMenu(reader);
}

private static void sortMenu(ReceiptReader reader){
{
  boolean work = true, writeback = true;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Then make changes to the `sortMenu()` method as such:

Assuming you are getting a good list returned from `reader.getReceipts`. As someone already noted you should change the array definition like below: As we already know `Receipt` objects are comparable.

```
ArrayList<Receipt> array = reader.getReceipts();
```

Then to sort the array using the `compareTo` method in the `Receipt` object change the line below. We use null to indicate we already know it is comparable and we want to use the default `compareTo` method, otherwise you could send over some other sort method and that’s why it doesn’t work as you have it posted.

```
array.sort(null);
```

I made those changes and it worked fine. Hope this helps.